# Is it possible to activate push notifications on an iOS app if the user chooses not to receive them initially?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The first time a user launches an iOS app using push notifications they are presented with an alert view asking them whether or not they want to receive them.

If the user selects no, the app does not show under the notification center in the system settings menu so they can not change their decision there. If they select yes when shown the alert view the app is visible in the settings and they can toggle notifications on and off at will.

If the user selects no, is there any way you can give them the option to turn push notifications on from within the app itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No , it is not possible , you have to go to setting for that .

in version below ios 5.0 , it is possible to open setting page from your app , by

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=yourpage"]];
```

but in newer version it is not possible.

Comment: by selecting no it will set No automatically to your setting.for your particular app

Comment: My mistake, it appears under "not in notification centre". Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

From within the app `its not possible`. User needs to enable it from `Settings` only